# How in powershell get current build definition

Tags: powershell

I have code, which on powershell get last successful build definition. How can I change code, that show last build. Or if build in progress, show current build?

```
 [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client")  
 [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client")  
 [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common")  

 $tfsCollectionUrl = "http://servertfs:8080/tfs/Test"
 $server = new-object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection(New-Object Uri($tfsCollectionUrl))
 $buildServer = $server.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.IBuildServer])
 $buildDetail = $buildServer.QueryBuilds("NameProject", "NameBuildDefinition") | where { $_.BuildDefinition.LastGoodBuildUri -eq $_.Uri } #| select BuildNumber
 $buildDetail
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the build of the online OS ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the filter that limits the results to 'last successful build' to get all the builds and apply an appropriate filter from there:

```
$buildDetail = $buildServer.QueryBuilds("NameProject", "NameBuildDefinition") | sort -desc StartTime | select -first 1
$buildDetail | ft BuildNumber, StartTime, Status
```

Extra: 
You might want to look at using a builddetailspec and specify MaxBuildsPerDefinition as it may be quicker if performance is an issue:  http://www.incyclesoftware.com/2012/09/fastest-way-to-get-list-of-builds-using-ibuildserver-querybuilds-2/

(edit: MaxBuildsPerDefinition on its own will get the first build, but somewhere to start)